# regex, only negate if whole word exists without another instance of part of word

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to return a string based on whether or not this plural word exists. If it exists, I want false, but if the singular part of it exists, I want true.

Example:

'cat\fish, cats' returns true because there is 'cat'
'fish, cats' returns false because there is no 'cat'
'cat\fish' returns true because there is no cats.

The statement only returns false if cats is by itself and there is no cat in it.

I tried working with a negative lookahead, `/^(?!.*cats).*$/ig` but it doesn't correctly recognise the case where there is a cat somewhere in the string.

Thank you!

Comment: So, you want to match any string that contains a whole word `cat`? `/\bcat\b/i`? Or any word starting with `cat` but not ending with `s`? Try [`/\bcat\B(?!s\b)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/XFRfxp/1)

Comment: any string that contains the whole word cat. But if cats is there and cat isn't, then don't match. `/\bcat\B(?!s\b)/i.test('zzzzcat')` gives me false. From what I understand, word boundaries limit regex to where there are spaces. This needs to work even if there aren't spaces

Comment: Ok, so it should be `/^(?!.*\bcats\b).*\bcat\b/i` - a whole word `cat` but no whole word `cats` is allowed. However, your question sounds rather unclear: I am afraid you misuse the "whole word" concept.

Comment: Just this one should work: `/cat(?!s)/`

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/cat(?!s)/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1cBjxu/3)

This regex finds text `cat` **anywhere** that must not be followed by a letter `s`.

Modifier `i` is used for making it case insensitive.